# How many Different ways to invoke JS inside a html Document?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

So far I know, 4 different ways to define & invoke JavaScript in webpage

1.inline JS

```
<script type='text/javascript'> ... </script>
```

2.External JS

```
<script src="someURL"></script>
```

3.Event hander JS:

```
<input type="button" onclick="...javascript..."
```

4.JavaScript:URL

```
<a href="javascript: ...JS CODE...">js</a>
```

**Is there any other ways JS can be inserted in a webpage ? Has it (how many ways) been defined in any standard Specification?**

**Is there any difference in the execution context of JavaScript among the mentioned 4 different ways?**

Comment: Do you want to know platform/framework specific ways?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish that's not handled by one of these 4 methods?

Comment: @BabakNaffas This question would apply well to attempting to strip out JS from user-submitted HTML.

Comment: @Kolink. But we answer the OP question, not what it can be possibly used for. He should mention what he wants to do if it's something "unique"...

Comment: Sounds like a homework question.

Answer (score 6):

There's actually quite a lot of ways to execute Javascript in HTML, all varying across browsers and platforms.

A lot of them (but not all) are listed in this [infamous XSS cheatsheet](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html).

Among less obscure ones, there are these:

```
<img src="javascript:...">
<body background="javascript:...">
<style>BODY{-moz-binding:url("...")}</style>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0;url=javascript:...">
```

...and so on.

Answer (score 1):

1 and 2 are basically the same, just that 2 is an external file and 1 has the content right there.

3 and 4 are along similar lines to `eval`. 3 defines `this` to be the element the event is on.

That's about it. If there are any other ways to include JS, I've never heard of them.

Comment: `<img src="javascript:alert('hello');">` should work in IE6 according to http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html

Comment: `this` is the window if you call a function. It's extremely important to say!